# Why when using escape key to go back to the main menu the preview camera is not working good?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a Render Texture named it : GUICameraRenderTexture

This is a screenshot of the Player camera :
I assigned to the Target Texture the new GUICameraRenderTexture :

[image: Player Camera]

Then on the bottom of the hierarchy I have a Main Menu > Camera :
The new Camera I changed the Clear Flags to Don't Clear and Culling Mask to Nothing :

[image: GUI Camera under Main Menu]

Then there is a Canvas the Canvas Render Mode is set to Screen Space - Overlay

And last the Raw Image I assigned to the Texture the GUICameraRenderTexture :

[image: Rae Image]

I want to start the game with the Player camera and then on escape key to switch to the main menu gui camera.

Screenshot if I'm disabling the main menu gui camera :

[image: No cameras to render]

Then I added a script to the Main Menu object :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Switch : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] cameras;
    public RenderTexture guiCameraRenderTexture;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            var cam0 = cameras[0].GetComponent<Camera>();
            cam0.targetTexture = guiCameraRenderTexture;

            cameras[1].SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

In the editor I disabled the new main menu gui camera and it's childs and enabled the player camera without the GUICameraRenderTexture the Target Texture is null on start.

When I hit the Escape key when the game is running it's showing the preview camera but also showing the player camera and not the main menu gui camera :

[image: Player Camera only]

On the escape key it should bring the main menu like in the first screenshot here. If I'm doing the changes removing the texture target and enable the gui camera it will work but using the script it's not working.

It's showing the player camera on both preview(rawimage) and gui camera.

The goal is to make the escape key to go to the main menu the gui main menu camera should be black and the player camera should be show in the preview rawimage.

Comment: I only see you enabling a camera .. did you check the `CullingMask` settings on your cameras? And also the depth? Higher depth will be rendered later -> on top. If they are equal the order in the Scene Hierachy is used..

Comment: Put the window in the Back so you do not see it.